# Custom Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to improve my code to find all the prime numbers within a set range as fast as possible, and I am trying to make it even faster. On my github page [here](https://github.com/DaveOwen/Prime-Sieve), I have some optimization settings within Visual Studio that help improve the speed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

#define RUNS 10000  // How many times the code will runs. I use run each section of code a set number of times, divide by that number
// to get the average. I had to to this because the program was running too fast for the GetTickCount() to get a speed.
#define RANGE 100000 // What number of primes to search up to
#define R2 RANGE/2
#define BRUNS 100000


int main()
{
    //Set up varibles
    int count;
    char primes[RANGE];
    int searchRange = sqrt(R2) + 1;
    DWORD starttime, endtime;

    //############################ SIEV #################################
    starttime = GetTickCount();

    for (int k = 0; k<RUNS; ++k)
    {
        count = 0;
        memset(primes, 0, R2);
        for (int i = 0; i < searchRange; ++i)
        {
            if (primes[i] == 0)
            {
                for (int j = (i << 1)*i + (i << 2) + (i << 1) + 3; j<R2; j += i * 4 + 6)
                {
                    primes[j] = 1;
                    primes[j + i * 2 + 3] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    endtime = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i<R2; i++) if (primes[i] == 0) count++;

    float totalOp = ((float)endtime - starttime) / (1000 * RUNS);
    //#####################################################################



    //#################### MEMSET FUNCTION TIMING TEST ####################
    // Here I am timing how long the memset function takes, so I can take that off the time for the sieve

    float totalMemset = ((float)endtime - starttime) / (1000 * RUNS);
    //#####################################################################




    //####################  OUTPUT TIME AND PRIMES  ######################
    std::cout << "Optimised Sieve Time:  ";
    std::cout << totalOp;
    std::cout << "\nPrimes Found: ";
    std::cout << count + 1;
    //#####################################################################
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the check `primes[i]==0`? Isn't it possible that the value in memory will be `0` even if it's not in the address range from `0` to `R2-1`?

Answer (score 2):

## Missing header

Include `<cstring>` to get a definition of `std::memset` (and add the missing namespace qualifier where you use it).

## Unused headers

We're not using `<bitset>`, `<fstream>` or `<string>`.

## Prefer C++ headers

Use `<cmath>` in preference to `<math.h>` for new code, to place the identifiers into the `std` namespace (the only identifier that needs updating where it's used is `std::sqrt`).

## Non-standard headers

Instead of platform-specific headers, you can use Standard C++ `<chrono>` for timing the code:

```
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto const starttime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    do_work();

    auto const endtime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    auto const time_in_ms =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endtime - starttime);

    std::cout << "Time taken:  "
              << time_in_ms.count() << " ms\n";
}
```

## Unused variable

We never use `totalMemset` - leaving it in makes your code look like it's not really ready for review.

## Use unsigned types

Most of the numbers used in this program are necessarily non-negative.  Prefer unsigned types to make this more apparent (and to give you twice as much range of values).

## Prefer constants to preprocessor macros

This is better, as it's strongly typed, and won't be expanded in the wrong context:

```
const std::size_t RUNS = 10000;
```

## Use `*` for arithmetic, not `<<`

An optimising compiler should generate the same code for

```
int j = (i << 1)*i + (i << 2) + (i << 1) + 3;
```

as for

```
int j = 2*i*i + 4*i + 2*i + 3;
```

The latter more clearly conveys your intent (and you could collect `4*i + 2*i` to simply `6*i`).  Don't attempt to micro-optimize this!

## Prefer range-based `for`

Instead of counting elements like this:

```
int count;
for (int i = 0; i<R2; i++) if (primes[i] == 0) count++;
```

Here's a simpler form:

```
std::size_t count = 0;
for (auto n: primes)
    count += !n;
```